# How to find dbcontext template in Visual Studio 11

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, templates, dbcontext, visual-studio-2012

I'm using database first approach to create a model with entity framework. In VS2010 after the model was generated I always choose a different code generation template (right click on diagram "Add new code generation item") then, in the dialog box, choose "DbContext Generator". This will instruct VS to generate POCO classes instead of the, very complex, standard class. When I tried to do the same in the Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview I can't find the template "DbContext Generator" in the dialog.
How can I add the dbcontext template to the Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview? 
I saw I can use nuget but I'm unable find it when I do a search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In February Microsoft release a dbContext Generator that works on Visual Studio 11 Beta.
The link to download this generator is:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/da740968-02f9-42a9-9ee4-1a9a06d896a2?SRC=VSIDE

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Can you add the [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) via the Extension Manager? Then in a class library, you can right-click and "Reverse Engineer Code First". That will pull your database in and create everything you need (no need for EDMX and TT files). You will need to have EF 4.1 installed or have added the EntityFramework NuGet package to your project before running reverse engineer.

I don't have VS 11 installed here, so can't check if the tools will install (I'm also not sure whether these features are being rolled into 11) but anyway will work great in 2010 as I frequently use it.

Richard